# Visual Studio: Debugging non localhost domain, locally

Tags: visual-studio

I have an entry in my hosts file that points somesite.com to 127.0.0.1 (localhost) so that I can test certain aspects of my web app (i goto http://somesite.com in a browser to test). Can someone suggest a way to debug a setup like this (in visual studio) that does not include using http://localhost?

I understand that this can most likely be done using remote debugger, if that is the best way can someone explain how thats setup (or a link to a good article).

Answer (score 0):

Set up a virtual machine, and run the web app in the VM. If you have two network adapters in the machine, you can even set things up so the network traffic goes out one, to a switch, and back in the other to the VM (I've done this sometimes so I could capture the traffic with WireShark).